# How do you output and modify the Content:Path variable using field:PHP global?

Tags: entities, views

I'm trying to modify the content:path variable using PHP field in Views for Drupal 7. The $data and the $row->path gives a blank result. Anyone know why?

It seems that I can grab it via the $views variable, but i have to dig deep into it in order to find it. Is there an easier to to access the content:path field via PHP in views?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve with this?

Comment: i am trying to do a regex find replace of the path url of the content url.

Comment: That's the method you are using to try to achieve something, it doesn't tell us what you're trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

To get the content id path data I had to get it from the $view variable:

```
$view->style_plugin->render_tokens[0]['path']
```

[image: Had to drill down into the $view object to find the path data.]

As seen below the $row->path data is NULL for some reason. Same goes for $data variable as that doesn't have any data at all.

[image: No Path data - shows only NULL]